# CoffeeScript TextMate Run Command

Tags: textmate, coffeescript

Can anyone assist with the TextMate Run command? I am not sure how to set the variable and its value in the TextMate in order to Run command + R and get the result of CoffeScript file. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After you install the tmbundle, as described in the first answer, in Preference Panel, select the Advanced tab and under TM_PATH add the path to coffee. To find out the path, type:

```
which coffee
```

at the command line.

If you installed using Homebrew, you'll get something like this for your path:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/Users/me/local/node/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

The `/usr/local/bin` part is where coffee is located.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Well, after running `which coffee` command, I get the `/usr/local/bin/coffee` output. I then place this output under the  advance tab into the textmate, using `TM_PATH` variable. However, I am still having trouble getting the run command working. I am not sure what am I doing wrong? Any thoughts, suggestions, appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to put `/usr/local/bin` in the path instead of `/usr/local/bin/coffee`. All `TM_PATH` needs is a search path, not an actual command.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! On my version of TextMate (2.0.0), that "advanced" variable was simply called `PATH` (see [official post](http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/TextMateAndThePath))

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. If `coffee` is in your `PATH` then everything should work fine. However, if not, I believe you can add it specifically for the shell that runs coffeescript using `TM_COFFEE`. It's up to the individual bundle what to do with the environment variables you leave for it. I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Install the CoffeeScript bundle:

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle

This will give you syntax highlighting and a lot more, including compilation.