# textmate bundle for coffeescript

Tags: javascript, textmate, coffeescript, textmatebundles

I'm trying to add the textmate bundle for coffeescript. 
I've followed the instructions on github - https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle

When I try to compile & display JavaScript I get the following error -

```
/tmp/temp_textmate.8hqQGD: line 12: coffee: command not found
```

I'm fairly certain it's due to my path being incorrect in textmate's preferences.

I'm trying to follow the instructions on this question -   [CoffeeScript TextMate Run Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397795/coffeescript-textmate-run-command) but I must be doing something wrong as It's not working.

When I do which coffee  I get /usr/local/bin/coffee

I've no TM_PATH variable in textmate's preferences only a PATH 
So, what should I put in my PATH variable in textmate? I currently have /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I've tried changing it to /usr/local/bin/ but when I try to run a command  I get

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/bash_init.sh: line 27: dirname: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `/usr/local/bin/` to the existing path, instead of replacing it entirely:

```
/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

should work for you. Personally, I'm using

```
~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

and the bundle is working correctly for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't really understand the formatting of the path. I presume the colons separate paths?

Comment: Yup, [it's described on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
echo $PATH
```

on the command line to see your current path. Copy+paste that into TextMate's preferences as the `TM_PATH`.

**Bonus tip**: Add a `NODE_PATH` variable to your TextMate preferences and paste your `$NODE_PATH` in if you want `require` statements to use the same paths in TextMate that they do from the command line. Here's my setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the NODE_PATH tip. Unfortunately the image doesn't show the full path. On my machine, with node installed locally this is: PATH "/Users/dave/local/node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" and NODE_PATH "/Users/dave/local/node:/Users/dave/local/node/lib/node_modules". You can check these values by typing "set" in terminal which will display a list of your environment variables.

Comment: Right, you wouldn't want to copy my `PATH` and `NODE_PATH` values directly anyway. Just check them in your shell, either using `set` or `echo $PATH` and `echo $NODE_PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add `/usr/local/bin` to your path and not override your path with only `/usr/local/bin`

so your path should look like: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

**edit**: you can add it like that: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thanks, works too. Afraid I'm going to give the answer to Jeremy as he got there first.

Comment: My answer was first ;-) but it doesn't matter. Glad i could help